# how to build blender controller and pickers

Tags: animation

Can someone point me to a tutorial on how to add controllers and pickers. I have the link to a youtube that I like to build.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nAWqQSH7fk

Comment: Take a look into drivers for Blender, this is what are you looking for mainly as for  the pickers you will need probably a custom made script tool in order to select/deselect on will the different parts.

Comment: Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please). It contains all kinds of information about how to ask a good question and why link-only questions are bad.

Comment: perfect, I wasn't sure what exactly to ask about after only seeing "real" examples!